# Задать максимальную высоту/ширину элементу iframe

Tags: html, html5, css3

Как задать максимальную высоту/ширину элементу iframe ?
Когда я пытаюсь задать в стилях css: max-height, max-width ничего не происходит. Но также ничего не происходит если прописать стили внутри самого тега iframe.

```
    <script>
$("#resizable").resizable(); <!-- растягиваем на своё усмотрение элемент iframe -->
</script>

<style>
iframe { resize: both; } <!-- стиль iframe растягивания -->
</style>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pnstyle.css">
    <title>Расчёты</title>

</head>
<body onload='slideToggle();'>

<center>

<table align="center" style="margin-top:-55px;">
<tr><td height="50px;">
</td></tr>

            <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="index.html"><b>Главная</a>
                <a href="raschetu.html"> Расчёты</a>
                <a href="reg.html">Войти</a>
                <a href="spravka.php">Справка</a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<div class="toggle_item">
<!--"расчёт 1"-->
<h3 class="toggle_triger">Расчёт колонны заливочных труб</h3>
<div class="toggle_content"> <!-- скрывваем/раскрываем контент расчёта -->
<iframe scrolling="no" height="330" width="650" frameborder="0" style="border: 2px solid black" src="pr1.html"></iframe> <!-- полоса прокрутки выключена, вместо неё пользователь будет растягивать подрасчёт, как он хочет -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: { height: 100%; width: 100%;} ? И надо указывать не максимальную, а минимальную тогда уж. Приведите пример вашего кода, или скриншоты которые показывают проблему

Comment: iframe должен "подстраиваться под содержимое контента, в моём случае это форма с таблицами, в которых ведутся расчёты

Comment: Наконец-то сам исправил, весь исправленный скрипт я кидаю в вопрос